# Quaterly,Weekly Date Functions in Google Bigquery

Tags: c#-4.0, google-bigquery

I am able to get Yearly and Daily,Day of week data from my table using functions [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#timestampfunctions).
But i need ways to achieve two more types of functions Quaterly and Weekly, Like DatePart in SQL Offers. Suggest any methods of achieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK is mentioned on the same page that you have linked to. This will help you to get the week day.

For quarter, a query something like this may work...

```
select INTEGER(INTEGER(SUBSTR(date_time, -14, 2))/3) AS QUARTER, count(date_time) as count
from company.summary GROUP BY QUARTER
```

I have the date time string as year-month-day + time format like...

> 2012-07-01 23:59:59

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this

EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date) as quarter

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(timestamp_usec,'date_format_str')` using the %m format to receive the month (1-12) and an if statement. An example would be:

> IF(STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(timestamp_usec,'%m') IN (1,2,3),'Q1',IF(STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(timestamp_usec,'%m') IN (4,5,6),'Q2',IF(STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(timestamp_usec,'%m') IN (7,8,9),'Q3','Q4')))

Answer (score 0):

## standard SQL

`CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q1'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q3'
    WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q4'
    END AS quarter`